# fingerprint sensor lenovo ideapad 520 ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

So I just bought the Lenovo Ideapad 520. It came with a fingerprint sensor. Most of my work though is with Ubuntu and I haven't really found a way to be able to use the fingerprint sensor with Ubuntu 17.10. A step by step walkthrough would really help as I don't want to feel like the sensor is useless.

Comment: Did you look at the fprintd package?  Realize, that while you can log in with the fingerprint sensor, you will still need a password to unlock the keyring for anything requiring it.

Comment: i did actually try the fprintd package. it wasn't able to detect the fingerprint sensor. is there a way to make the hardware visible to the application?

Comment: What hardware do you have for your biometric sensor?  Thinkpad W520 comes with:   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor  (output from lsusb). This hardware works with fprintd.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think it is: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc.